# Where is the appropriate place to defend against undefined input in a single-page angular app?

Tags: angularjs, forms, error-handling

(This may be too loose a question for Stack Overflow, but I figured it was worth a shot.) I'm new at Angular trying to wrap my head around the appropriate use of different components as I run through some tutorials and a lot of them skip over proper error handling procedure/decoupling.

Take a simple login form that queries a Mongo database (no fancy Passport stuff yet). Just a username and password box and that's it. The happy path (which I'm sure you Angular pros can already guess) is:

- the html template makes a call to the controller for that page
- the controller calls the auth factory to process the request, passing along the username/password
- the Auth factory hits the RESTful api (which is an express router) which makes use of the User model
- the User model takes the login information and queries the database and returns something, and it returns up the chain (the distinction here is blurry because the User model is injected into the express router, but I think you get the idea)

Now, if the user hits the button without entering anything, at some point I'll want to check this and respond accordingly. My inclination is to do this as close to the source of the error as possible - the controller - but I'm unsure about whether this is the 'correct' use of the controller. My other inclination is to make everything be agnostic until the end of the chain, but I'm also unsure if this is the 'correct' use of the model.

Is there a best practice here?

Comment: I believe your first intuition is correct, and you should deal with this type of validation in the controller. Recall that the controller is pretty much the intermediary between your model and the view. So anything related to the view, that will eventually affect your model, should be handled in the controller including validation IMO.

Comment: This seems like the kind of validation that the built in angular validators are made for.  You definitely don't want to send a model from the client to the server only to have the server reject it when you have a way to avoid that; angular is all about minimizing the round trip interactions with the server when possible.

Comment: But you'd still have to have some validation on the model side in case of, say, a request made via POSTMAN, right?

Comment: You always need server side validation, javascript in browser can be easily bypassed. Catch what you can though client side